# $ Error running an executable from SQLPLUS

Tags: python, executable, sqlplus

I have created this executable out of a python script. All it does is prints 'Hello World'. I am trying to run this off SQLPlus. 
My SQlPlus query is as provided below:

```
START 'C:\USERS\ADMINISTRATOR\DESKTOP\dist\HW.exe'
```

I keep getting the following error:

[image]

Using 'Host', gives:

[image]

Any help/suggestion/edits would be appreciated.

I have also plainly tried to run the python script 'HW.py' resulting in the following error:

[image]

What is the right way to execute the HW.exe from SQLPlus?

Comment: how did you create the executable?

Comment: Using Py2exe, a python package.